# String with Links and different font styles in Swift 3

Tags: string, swift3, styles

I've been trying to achieve this:

Basically: A very simple line of text including 2 links. These two link being in semibold when the rest of the text is in regular.

Was trying to get everything done into the same string using the Storyboard.

Surprisingly, it seems to be quite hard to achieve. I can't get myself to understand why something that simple should be so hard. Was expecting to achieve this in the Storyboard view...

[Please view the images by clicking this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxQFW.png)

Thank you all for your help!

Quentin

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with storyboard, but you can do it this way programmatically:

first make your label

```
yourLabel: UILabel =
{
    let label = UILabel()

    return label
}()
```

Now, to have some text be bold and the rest not, you need to declare a NSMutableAttributedString and then append it on another string, like this:

```
yourLabel: UILabel =
{
    let label = UILabel()

    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your Text   Here", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)])

    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Your Bold Blue Text Here", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)]))

    label.attributedText = attributedText

    return label
}()
```

You can now also set one of the strings to be a link/button and the other not.

Hope it helps.